# Python web communication between files

Tags: python, web, pygame

I have my game created in pygame and now i want to create some sort of multiplayer, where one player will be hosting and the other will join the room. At the moment i have no idea about internet connection between two programs on different PCs and haven't found anything on google either. Thanks for any clues

Comment: it is not place for this kind of question. Here you have to show your code and error message.

Comment: Okay, i'll remember. But if you could, tell me at least where should i search for the answer

Comment: [Pygame.org](http://www.pygame.org/tags/all), [Mastermind Networking Lib](http://www.pygame.org/project-Mastermind+Networking+Lib-859-.html), [inventwithpython](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2010/09/01/the-top-10-pygame-tutorials/)

Comment: SO group [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pygame)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets. Right now I'm working on a multiplayer game its still in bata so i can't show it to you but i can give you my subprogram that simplify sockets. I suggest learning about sockets first so you can understand my program beater. here's a tutorial I used:

https://www.youtube.com/watchv=Q1a12QFq3os&index=1&list=WL

My code with an example:

https://gist.github.com/Blackwolf04

it's the Format_.py and Format_example.py